# Laravel upload any size of file in Google Drive

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api, laravel-5.4

I am currently developing a Laravel 5.4 app running on PHP 7. I am using Google Drive as my storage.I am trying to upload large file,size of 200-300 mb or small file of 10-12 kb to my google drive storage using `nao-pon/flysystem`.For this,I have followed this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/ivanvermeyen/cc7c59c185daad9d4e7cb8c661d7b89b.
I have changed my php.ini like this:

```
post_max_size = 800M

upload_max_filesize = 700M
```

I can upload small file.The problem occurred when I am trying to upload large file,size of 200-250 mb,the alotted php `memory_limit` surpasses and I get error.

**I have used this controller method**

```
$files = $request->file('files');
if($request->hasFile('files')){

foreach ($files as $file) {

$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$disk = Storage::disk('google'); 
$disk->put($name, File::get($file));

     }
      }
```

So,I have searched google, how can I upload large file without surpassing the

```
memory_limit
```

and I get this for Amazon S3 and I modified it for Google drive:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('google');
$disk->put($name, fopen($file, 'r+'));
```

But,now I am getting another error trying to upload any size of file (10kb-300mb):

```
(1/1) ErrorException
A non well formed numeric value encountered

in GoogleDriveAdapter.php (line 1143)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'A non well formed numeric value encountered', '/app/vendor/nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive/src/GoogleDriveAdapter.php', 1143, array('iniName' => 'memory_limit', 'val' => '128M', 'last' => 'm'))in GoogleDriveAdapter.php (line 1143)]
```

This method is working fine for Local storage.But not for google drive.
So, my question is,is there any way or package out there which is simple and I can implement it easily to upload any size of file to my google drive without any hassel.

Comment: it could be your webserver acting out. Did you change the upload size for your webserver?

Comment: yeah,I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the `nao-pon/flysystem` package.Using the new package or 
 `composer update` will solve the problem.